# JQuery can't call css method twice at a time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a codepen where I am recreating (recreating because I saw this in someone else's pen) a loading icon that looks like a newton's cradle. That codepen can be found [here](http://codepen.io/DITTODITTO/pen/zqoyjr).

My issue is that I want the balls to change their background color to the same color as their border when they swing out and change back to transparent when they return to the center.

I thought that I could just change the color before and after I animate each ball within the moveRight and moveLeft functions, but that doesn't seem to be working for whatever reason. I have checked the syntax of the JQuery functions several times, but can't seem to find an error with how I am calling them.

At first, I believed that the issue has something to do with setting the balls to be transparent, but I have (I believe) debunked that theory. My new theory is that it is trying to call the css function twice at a time on two different elements and is just malfunctioning as a result. I'm not sure that this is true however, as the function should be terminated before it is called again, right?

Every time I call either function, I pass a parameter similar to '#1-1'. This is the id of one of the five dots, the second digit representing the number (so the first is 1-1, second 1-2, etc. The animation is working, so I would assume that there is no issue with the selectors inside of the functions.

Can someone shed some light on this issue? Is this just a codepen problem? I have been having lots of issues in the past relating to backgroundcolor on the web, both on codepen and JSFiddle, so that could be the reason. I don't think that this is the problem though because in another pen I got backgroundcolor setting to work only with JQuery.

Here is the javascript that is causing me problems:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.setInterval(function() {
    moveRight('#1-1');
    moveRight('#1-2');
  }, 1000);
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.setInterval(function() {
      moveLeft('#1-3');
      moveLeft('#1-4');
      moveLeft('#1-5');
    }, 1000);
  }, 500);
});

function moveRight(id) {
  $(id).css("background-color", "#00094F");
  $(id).animate({
    marginLeft: "-=70",
    marginTop: "-=50",
  }, 250, function() {
    $(id).animate({
      marginLeft: "+=70",
      marginTop: "+=50",
    }, 250);
  });
  $(id).css("background-color", "#78FF81");
}

function moveLeft(id2) {
  $(id).css("background-color", "#00094F");
  $(id2).animate({
    marginLeft: "+=70",
    marginTop: "-=50",
  }, 250, function() {
    $(id2).animate({
      marginLeft: "-=70",
      marginTop: "+=50",
    }, 250);
  });
  $(id).css("background-color", "#78FF81");
}
```

EDIT: My newest issue is that when I try to change the background colors before and after each animation call, the left three dots that call moveLeft don't do anything anymore, not even animate. Something is definitely amiss here, any ideas for this too?

Comment: When you update the background color immediately after updating it previously, all you'll see is the most recent update. The browser won't repaint the view in between. Also, note that your `.animate()` calls schedule the animation but they return **immediately**.

Comment: It's not super-clear to me what the actual issue is; a runnable example might help. The only thing immediately obvious is that you're calling `css` before your animations end.

Comment: Great to know! What do you suggest for that delay? Do I need to use window.Timeout()?

Comment: @Pointy Also, I want to add that when I only change the colors of the elements at the top of the animate call, not below, only the right balls animate (the ones that are called first). Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Consider the following [forked codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqobdM). Is this inline with what you are trying to achieve. It also addresses your second concern I believe.

Comment: Um this is just a recommendation but rather than use setInterval jquery is often more efficiently run when using requestAnimationFrame instead

Comment: Thanks Nikitas! That is exactly what I wanted, and I feel terrible for not coming up with that solution myself!

Comment: It's my pleasure, glad it helped and that I parted some knowledge to someone out there :D

Answer (score 0):

Try placing it in a animate complete function:

```
  //place this inside of your animate function as a property 
  complete:function() {

   $(id).css("background-color", "#78FF81");

   });
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with complete and cannot find a reference to it on google, can you give me a brief explanation? It doesn't seem to be doing anything, nor does it run the rest of the code.